ROS2 example application using loan mechanism for subscriber/listener not found under ROS2 demos
I'm currently trying to run ROS2 publisher & subscriber application using loan APIs (ROS2 DISTRO - Humble with DDS - FastDDS).
I have found a ROS2 demo application for loan message API in publisher side .
No loan API example implementation found for corresponding subscriber side?
Is there any application available?
It will be of great help if anyone can provide some light on this. Thanks in advance.

Given this issue and this remark still being in the code in rolling, I conclude that it is not supported yet.
In the issue following is mentioned:

The only way to use zero-copy on the subscription side is through an executor which uses rcl_take_loaned_message directly.

So I suggest to have a look at that issue, and at its draft PR.

Is there any example applications available which uses executor with loan APIs at subscription side ?

I am not aware of any. I suggest to read up on ROS  Discourse posts, as well as on all documentation and the Github issues which are refered to, e.g. here, here, here. Note the following: "[...] because they are disabled by default [...] (as they are currently unsafe to use)."

Here is a repository, not sure if it is still relevant though (3y old).

Coincidentally, I found this example repository. I did not try it though...
